# Is it possible to get client os user name in java web application?

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, jakarta-ee, applet

i have website hosted on local server and this website is accessed by several local users, and i want when they access specific page to get the os user for the client/user accessing this page, when i tried the java code:

```
String currentUser=System.getProperty("user.name");
```

it gets the os user name for the server not the client.

please advise how to accomplish that, thanks.

Comment: Can you give some example what you are getting and what you want ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ, i am getting os user name for server not for client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using java method `request.getRemoteUser()` did the trick.

Comment: I get null from request.getRemoteUser(), Can anyone help me? I have tried:

String userProperty = System.getProperty("user.name");

    String userNTSystem = new com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem().getName();
    
    Principal principal = request.getUserPrincipal();
    
    String userGetenv = System.getenv("USERNAME");
    
    String remoteUser = request.getRemoteUser();

Answer (score 0):

```
String userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
```

You can get a full list of all user-agent values from this web site,
http://www.user-agents.org/

**Javascript Way**

```
var OSName="Unknown OS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) OSName="Windows";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) OSName="MacOS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11")!=-1) OSName="UNIX";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) OSName="Linux";
```

and send the OSName variable back to the server.

Comment: That includes the OS in braces. For example `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.69 Safari/537.36`

Comment: @Deepak Mishra, i know about user agent, it can't help to get os user name.

Comment: i am talking about OS USER NAME NO OS NAME !

Comment: It's in the environment variable "USERNAME". you can't access that from javascript.

Comment: Why don't you **ask the user** and navigate to the required page accordingly. You can use a drop down if you already know the set of users.

Comment: Thats not possible to get the os username. unless client creates some utility to share his username.

Comment: @Deepak Mishra, i was asking if that is possible by any way.

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh  There's no simple solution to it. You can try this though... http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0441.html. They say its possible with IE.

Answer (score 0):

Create jar which consist of applet where applet can get current user name by using `System.getProperty("user.name")`
write httpclient in same applet where it sends current user name to servlet which is on your server.

1. call current user method is applet
2. assign username to httpclient
3. send user name to servlet using httpclient

Your program give username of server not the client that's why you have to user client side technology like applet which resides in client machine.

Comment: i am not experienced with applets, can you please add sample code for this applet ?

Comment: is your problem solved by looking to other comments or is you find any other technology apart from applet.